# How to backup files from a phone that's constantly freezing 20 seconds after turning it on

Tags: data-recovery

So I have a Huawei P Smart that's freezing 20 seconds after I open it **and** type its password for the first time. And after that, 2 minutes later, it's restarting.

I would like to save the photos and files from it before I factory reset it, but the computer simply doesn't have the time to save anything before the phone freezes. I have the time to enable USB debugging and data to access tho'.

I have tried opening it in safe mode, I googled and watched videos on youtube, but I couldn't retrieve anything.

Comment: What have you tried to prevent freezing? Connect charger, enable airplane mode, deinstall unused apps, keep the phone cool...

Comment: Is the device rooted? Does it have a custom recovery? The latter usually offers you ways to get data off the device.

Comment: it's a 2018 device. Huawei stopped unlocking bootloader 2018